# In Javascript, can you use template literals to console.log content from an object while iterating over it?

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, console.log, template-literals

So I am less than 1 week into learning JS and I've been trying to find a solution but other than an answer involving functions and something to do with JSON.stringify (which I don't understand) I cannot seem to find one. Rather than using string concatenation when iterating over this object I want to use template literals to display specific information from each property. Is that possible?

```
pokemonList = [
  {name: 'Bulbasur', height: 70, weight: 15.2, type: ['grass','poison']},
  {name: 'Charmander', height: 60, weight: 18.7, type: ['fire']},
  {name: 'Squirtle', height: 50, weight: 19.8, type: ['water']}
];

for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${pokemonList.name[i]} ${pokemonList.height[i]}`);
};
```

Comment: Hi, should be pokemonList[i].name

Comment: What's the problem with `JSON.stringify()`? The method converts its argument into [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), a textual representation of it.

Comment: @Andreas maybe OP just wants to print some of the properties and in a specific format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can! You just need to change `pokemonList.name[i]` to `pokemonList[i].name`.

The `pokemonList` is the one that has elements within it, so you use `pokemonList[i]` to access an element within it, and then `pokemonList[i].name` will give you the name property of that element.

Here's the fixed code:

```js
pokemonList = [
  {name: 'Bulbasur', height: 70, weight: 15.2, type: ['grass','poison']},
  {name: 'Charmander', height: 60, weight: 18.7, type: ['fire']},
  {name: 'Squirtle', height: 50, weight: 19.8, type: ['water']}
];

for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${pokemonList[i].name} ${pokemonList[i].height}`);
};
```

`JSON.stringify` on the other hand will print the entire object as a string, and it will look similar to how it looks in the list above within your code:

```js
pokemonList = [
  {name: 'Bulbasur', height: 70, weight: 15.2, type: ['grass','poison']},
  {name: 'Charmander', height: 60, weight: 18.7, type: ['fire']},
  {name: 'Squirtle', height: 50, weight: 19.8, type: ['water']}
];

for (let i=0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(pokemonList[i]));
};
```

Answer (score 3):

you have an error in for loop
You should replace your [i] to pokemontList, not to pokemonList's property `${pokemonList[i].name} ${pokemonList[i].height}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringifay for every item in array:

```
pokemonList.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```